# How to check Tic-Tac-Toe Winner

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I want to know what is wrong with my code. I made a tic-tac-toe game using a table in the body of the website and javascript. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

INSIDE BODY:

```
<body>
    </table>

    <table id="matrix" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="cellCSS">
                <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,0)"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellCSS">
                <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,1)"/>
            </td>
            <td class="cellCSS">
                <img alt="Click Here" class="imageCSS" onclick="imageClicked(this,0,2)"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</body>
```

And this is the relevant part of the function imageClicked:

```
...
same = false;
var r = 0;
tbl = document.getElementById("matrix");
//alert(tbl.rows.length);

for(r = 0; r < tbl.rows.length; r++) {
    // alert('Bob');
    var _tempmg = tbl.rows[r].cells[col].childNodes[0].src;
    alert(_tempmg);
    if (!_tempmg) break;
    if (_img.src != _tempmg) break;
    same = true;
}

if (r == tbl.rows.length && same) {
    alert(_img.src + "won");
    return;
}

same = false;
...
```

Comment: On a side note, you'd do better to store your data within an array, rather than within the `</table>` itself

Comment: Might be worth a look at my tic tac toe game.  http://goo.gl/vgMT9

Also can be found at http://trcxbox.trcx.in/TicTacToe.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that r == tbl.rows.length is always false, because the for loop iterates while r < tbl.rows.length.

Comment: r = tbl.rows.length if the loop went all the way through (i.e. break wasn't called or was called on the last iteration)

Answer (score 0):

You should include a bit more of the *imageClicked* function. I'll guess that it starts:

```
function imageClicked(element, row, col) {
```

and in your posted code:

```
same = false;
```

Presumably you've declared same earlier to keep it local.

```
var r = 0;
```

There is no need to initialise r here (i.e. assign it a value) if you do so in the loop.

```
tbl = document.getElementById("matrix");

for(r = 0; r < tbl.rows.length; r++) {
    var _tempmg = tbl.rows[r].cells[col].childNodes[0].src;

    if (!_tempmg) break;
```

In your html, you have not assigned a value to the image src attribute, so I would have thought that at this point you'd assign a naught or cross depending on who had clicked on it. Having assigned an appropriate image, I would execute the next line.

```
    if (_img.src != _tempmg) break;
    same = true;
```

It might be clearer to add a condition to the for(...) expression like:

```
for(r = 0; r < tbl.rows.length && !same; r++) {
```

Now instead of break you can use:

```
    if (_img.src == _tempmg) same = true;
```

.

```
}

if (r == tbl.rows.length && same) {
    alert(_img.src + "won");
    return;
}

same = false;
```

I need to see more of the *imageClicked* function to understand why it isn't working.